# Limiting the display of password_hash

Tags: php

I am currently displaying the password using the password_hash function and since it's too long, it causes the contents to overflow in the table. I know I have to use substr but I can't get it right. Here's my code:

```
 <?php echo password_hash('$row->Password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT). "\n";?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
substr(String, START_POSITION, END_POSITION)
<?php echo substr(password_hash('$row->Password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT), 0, 50). "\n";?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew the syntax. I just can't figure out where to put it in. Thanks again!